# Sqlite.swift -- Selecting all rows and returning them in an array of tuples

Tags: swift, sqlite

[Link to SQLite wrapper](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift)

```
func queryAll() -> [(String, String, String)]  {
    do {
        let sql = try DB?.prepare("SELECT city, zip , temp FROM weather")
        var arr : [(city : String, zip : String, temp : String)] = []
        for row in sql! {
            arr += [(city: row[0] as! String, zip: row[1] as! String, temp: row[2] as! String)]               
        }
        return arr;            
    }
    catch {
        print("\(error)")
    }
    return [("","","")]
}
```

Grabbing all the rows, and returning them as a tuple for later use.
I've read the docs but I cannot think of a more efficient way to return all the rows to a TableView

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell : CustomTableViewController = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")! as! CustomTableViewController
    let DB : WeatherDataStorage = WeatherDataStorage()
    var arr = [(city : String, zip : String, temp : String)]()
    arr = DB.queryAll()
    cell.cityLabel.text = arr[i].city
    cell.zipLabel.text = arr[i].zip
    cell.temperatureLabel.text = arr[i].temp
    i += 1
    return cell
}
```

EDIT: [GIST](https://gist.github.com/J2quared/12f82d3849e7adf56fb607b228142e44)

Comment: Is that your working code? I wonder about `let cell : CustomTableViewController` because a cell cannot be a view controller.

Comment: Cell is a custom table view cell class

Comment: But then `let cell : CustomTableViewController` makes no sense. Please post your actual working code. – The definitions of `DB` and `WeatherDataStorage` would also be relevant.

Comment: Suggestion: It is not necessary to define the type of a variable/constant that can be inferred by both the compiler and someone reading the call site. It adds additional noise when reading your code. Instead of `let cell: CustomTableViewController...` you can declare it as `let cell = self.tableView...`

Comment: Also, it would be more appropriate to name `DB` as `db` as per Swift's API Design Guidelines. Or in this case, something like `dataStore`.

Comment: Hey Joseph, have I answered your question? If so, please mark it as accepted

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Don't use tuples like this. The purpose of tuples is to make simple, *short lived* collections of values. For a use case like this, it is preferable to use a `struct` or a `class` to contain your results. There are **many** disadvantages.
2. Don't return non-sensical default values as a way of error handling. `""` isn't a city, and `""` isn't a valid zip code, so why try to claim them as such? This is what optionals are for, use them.
3. Narrow your `do` block to contain only the function calls that `throw`.
4. Avoid force casting if you can. Handle your errors sensibly.
5. Currently, you manually create an empty array, and repeatedly add to it in a for loop. This is discouraged for several reasons:
6. `arr` must be mutable.
7. It's a lot of boiler-plate code.
8. You can incur a lot of reallocation overhead, because you didn't call `reserveCapacity` on your array.

Using `map` is preferable instead.

6. Improve your naming. `sql` is a result set, it's not an `sql` code snippet, nor is it an sql connection. Name it so.
7. Don't use the pattern of: `array += [newElement]`. This technique causes an unnecessary array allocation. Instead, just use `array.append(newElement)`.
8. Change your `DB` variable to not be an `Optional`. If there is something like a connection issue that causes `DB` to be `nil`, this should be handled at the time that you attempt to open the connection. Leaving it as an `Optional`, and using optional chaining `DB?.doSomething()` is a **terrible** idea. It makes the `nil` case fail silently, leading to very annoying to catch bugs.
9. "weather" is an awkward name for a table. Try something like "WeatherReading"

Here's how I would write this code:

```
struct WeatherReading {
    let city: String
    let zipCode: String
    let temperature: String
}

func queryAllWeatherReadings() -> [WeatherReading]?  {
    guard let queryResults = try? DB.prepare("SELECT city, zip, temperature FROM WeatherReading") else {
        debugPrint(error)
        return nil
    }

    let weatherReadings = queryResults.map { row in
        guard let city = row[0] as? String,
              let zipCode = row[1] as? String,
              let temperature = row[2] as? String else {
            fatalError("There was a type error in the received result set: \(row)")
        }

        return WeatherReading(city: city, zipCode: zipCode, temperature: temperature)
    }

    return weatherReadings
}
```